# react-native : How to fetch posts from a public facebook page?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is more a general question than a problem.

I'm developing a react native application, and i need to integrate a page that shows facebook posts.

However, i can't see how to fetch posts from the page, please note that it's a public page.

How could i fetch posts from a facebook public page using react native?

Comment: You should refrain from using Stack Overflow for asking opinion based questions

Answer (score 1):

Before stepping into ReactNative, you should first plan how to fetch data from facebook.

Facebook offers the Graph API, which suits your needs.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/

Here is the docs specifically for Facebook pages.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/

The response from the API is usually in JSON format, then you can use the fetch API of javascript in ReactNative.

I strongly suggest doing the API calls on your server tho.